# Killing SignalR cross domain connection

Tags: signalr

I'm not entirely sure how to even ask this question, so here's the situation:

1. We have a single-page application that connects to a SignalR hub that uses CORS for cross domain authentication
2. The user connects to the hub and leaves their browser window open
3. We delete the user, but since they already connected to the hub, anytime they go back to that page (without reloading), the hub reconnects
4. Restarting IIS has no effect

So that's the situation and I think I understand *why* it's happening, what I don't know is the best practice for keeping this from happening in the future (I originally thought expiring the session but since this is a single page application as long as they don't refresh, it'd never call the session timeout).

Is there an easy way server side to kill a connection (we log all connections so have connection ids, etc)?

Thanks for the guidance!  I'm stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot stop a connection from server side. To stop the connection, you need to call `$.connection.hub.stop();` from the client side

One way to stop the connection is to create a function in Client side, then call it from Server

Client Side

```
myHub.client.serverWantDisconnect = function (value) {
    $.connection.hub.stop();
};
```

Server Side

```
Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).serverWantDisconnect();
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured.  I had this workaround in mind just felt like there should have been a better alternative.  I'll mark this as the answer since that's what I'll end up doing.